# TypeError when re-configuring a text widget using information from another widgets entry field

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget, typeerror

I have a Tkinter GUI that is composed of two widgets, the first is a widget class with an entry field and a button and the second is a scrollable text widget class. I have combined these two widget classes to make a single GUI. Each of these widget classes works correctly as individuals.

The text field of the GUI is being used to display the contents of a specific index of a list. I want to be able to enter an index number in the entry field and upon pressing the button the text in the text field is re-configured to show the contents of the list for the specified index. However when I press the button I get the following error message:

> " File "/Users/BioASys/BioasysDB/testgui.py", line 25, in
>   fetch_update_text
>   article_review_widget_assembled.update_text(article_index) TypeError:
>   unbound method update_text() must be called with
>   article_review_widget_assembled instance as first argument (got int
>   instance instead)"

When I initialize (mainloop) the GUI I have the text widget set to display the 0 index of the list.

I have written simplified code that exhibits my problem. My original code is too complex to sensibly post here. Because of the layout of all the individual widgets in my original code it was necessary to combine multiple widget classes to achieve my desired widget layout.

If anybody has any thoughts on how to get these two widgets to communicate I would greatly appreciate the assistance.

Here is the simplified code I have written which exhibits the issue I am having.

---

```
from Tkinter import *

# This list contains the sample text 
# that is to be placed in the individual text widgets, 
# referenced by index
text_list = [['text0AAAAAAA'], ['text1AAAAAAA'], ['text2AAAAAAA']]

# This class creates the widget that will be designated top_left 
# in the article_review_widget_assembled widget

class article_review_entry_button_widget(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH) 
        self.index = 2
        self.makeWidgets()

    def handleList(self, event):
        index = self.listbox.curselection()
        label = self.listbox.get(index)
        self.runCommand(label)

    def fetch(self):                                    
        # This def gets the value placed in the entry field
        print 'Input => "%s"' % self.ent.get()
        article_index = self.ent.get()

    def fetch_update_text(self):                        
        #  This def gets the value placed in the entry field 
        # and also attempts to access the update_text def 
        # to update the text in the  top_right widget
        print 'Input => "%s"' % self.ent.get()
        article_index = int(self.ent.get())
        # It is this line that is generating the TypeError

        # It is this line that is generating the TypeError
        article_review_widget_assembled.update_text(article_index)  

    def makeWidgets(self):
        self.ent = Entry(self)
        btn = Button(self, text='Next Article', command=self.fetch_update_text)
        self.ent.insert(0, 0)
        self.ent.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
        self.ent.focus()
        self.ent.bind('<Return>', (lambda event: self.fetch()))
        value = self.ent.get()
        btn.pack(side=TOP)
```

---

```
class ScrolledText(Frame):                      
    # This class creates a text widget that can be scrolled, 
    # I use this as the basis for the other text widgets in this GUI

    def __init__(self, parent=None, text='', file=None, 
                 width='', height=''):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH) 
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.makewidgets()
        self.settext(text, file)

    def makewidgets(self):
        sbar = Scrollbar(self)
        text = Text(self, relief=SUNKEN, width=self.width, height=self.height)
        sbar.config(command=text.yview)                  
        text.config(yscrollcommand=sbar.set)
        sbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)last
        text.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH) 
        self.text = text

    def settext(self, text='', file=None):
        self.text.delete('1.0', END)                    
        self.text.insert('1.0', text)
        self.text.mark_set(INSERT, '1.0') 
        self.text.focus()

    def gettext(self)
        return self.text.get('1.0', END+'-1c')
```

---

```
class article_review_widget_assembled(Frame):        
     # This class uses the previous classes 
     # to create the final assemnbeld GUI widget

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)    
        self.text = text_list[0]
        self.makeWidgets()

    # This is the def that is called by the fetch_update_text def 
    # in the article_review_entry_button_widget class
    def update_text(index):
        self.top_right.configure(text=text_list[index])
        print "The index is:", index

    def makeWidgets(self):
        self.top_left = article_review_entry_button_widget(self).pack(side=LEFT)
        self.top_right = ScrolledText(self, text= self.text, width=50, height=15).pack(side=LEFT)
```

---

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #article_review_entry_button_widget().mainloop()
    #ScrolledTextComposite().mainloop()
    article_review_widget_assembled().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you created a class (`article_review_widget_assembled`), created an instance of that class (`article_review_widget_assembled()`), but then tried to access a method by treating it like a static method (`article_review_widget_assembled.update_text(article_index)`).

The proper way to call `update_text` as you have defined it is via an instance of that class. That is what the message `TypeError: unbound method update_text() must be called with article_review_widget_assembled instance as first argument (got int instance instead)` is telling you. "unbound method" means you're calling a method designed to be "bound" to an instance, but you're not calling it via an instance.

The solution is to call it via an instance. Fortunately, in your case you're passing the reference to `article_review_entry_button_widget` as the `parent` parameter, so it looks like you can call it like `self. parent.update_text()` if you also set `self.parent` to the value of the `parent` parameter:

```
class article_review_entry_button_widget(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        ...

    def fetch_update_text(self):                        
        ...
        self.parent.update_text(article_index)
```

Bottom line: when you get an "unbound method" error, it means you're calling a method via a class rather than via an instance of the class. These errors are a bit easier to spot if you adhere to the convention of starting class names with uppercase characters and instances with lowercase. This makes your code much easier to read and understand (eg: `Article_review_entry_button`, etc)

Comment: Hello, Thank you for you assistance. I understand everything in the first two paragraphs and I also understand that I need to call the update_text method with an instance, but I am unclear on the rest of your third paragraph's meaning.

Comment: When I make the changes you suggest, and I am using your changes exactly as you present them, I get the following error message: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/BioASys/BioasysDB/simpletestgui.py", line 126, in <module>
    article_review_widget_assembled().mainloop()
  File "/Users/BioASys/BioasysDB/simpletestgui.py", line 102, in __init__
    this.parent = parent
NameError: global name 'this' is not defined".                         Unfortunately I still don't know how to solve my problem. Sincerely, George

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped one of your suggestions. However I still received an error message after making the correction. The error message was:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/BioASys/BioasysDB/simpletestgui.py", line 126, in <module>
    article_review_widget_assembled().mainloop()
  File "/Users/BioASys/BioasysDB/simpletestgui.py", line 106, in __init__
    self.makeWidgets()
  File "/Users/BioASys/BioasysDB/simpletestgui.py", line 115, in makeWidgets
    self.top_left = article_review_entry_button_widget(self).pack(side=LEFT)
  File "/Users/BioASys/BioasysDB/simpletestgui.py", line 40, in __init__
    this.parent = parent
NameError: global name 'this' is not defined

Comment: @user3798654: oops, my mistake. Use `self``, not `this`. I've updated my answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the clarification. Am I correct in assuming that "this" should be changed to "self" on both 1) this.parent.update_text(article_index) and 2) this.parent = parent. You only changed this to self in one of the two lines in your edit. However when I made the correction (in both lines)  I get the following error message:

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/BioASys/BioasysDB/simpletestgui.py", line 56, in fetch_update_text
    self.parent.update_text(article_index)
TypeError: update_text() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: @user3798654: that error is telling you exactly what the problem is. You're calling the function with two arguments (the implicit "self", plus another argument), but the function accepts only the one argument "self".

Comment: OK, So I think the solution to this error is to change "def update_text(index):" to "def update_text(self,index):". However when I make this change I get the following error:

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/BioASys/BioasysDB/simpletestgui.py", line 56, in fetch_update_text
    self.parent.update_text(article_index)
  File "/Users/BioASys/BioasysDB/simpletestgui.py", line 110, in update_text
    self.top_right.configure(text=text_list[index])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'configure'

Comment: It appears that the fetch_update_text(self) method is now correctly accessing the update_text(self,index) method (after adding self to the update_text parameters) but that the configure method is not the correct way to rewrite the text contained within self.top.right. Am I interpreting this correctly and if so what would be the correct way to change the text within a text widget?

Comment: @user3798654: I'm sorry, but I can't be a personal debugger for you. You can ask another question, but please first try to solve the problem on your own. Trust the error message is telling you the truth, and try to understand what it is telling you. The questions you are asking have been asked about many times on this site, and can be solved with very basic debugging skills.

Comment: Hi, Again thank you for your help. I appreciate that you are not meant to be my personal debugger, as much as I wish something like that existed. Can you verify if I am correct in changing the parameters in update_text to (self, index) from (index) is correct? Thanks, George